# Doors DXL Check for links between modules

Tags: ibm-doors

first of all Im quite new to Doors and dxl.

We have three modules to manage our requirements. Basically the structure is like this.

Module1 -> Module2 -> Module3
Module4 -> Module2 -> Module3

Each requirement in Module1 has at least one requirement in Module2. Same for Module2 -> Module3.

Im looking for a way to programatically change a attribute in Module3, whether the requirement has a link to Module1 or Module4

If for example a requirement in Module3 is traceable to Module1, I need to change a attribute in the requirement from Module3.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

depending on your concrete needs, it sounds like you might want to use a DXL layout column or a DXL attribute.
You can the Analysis Wizard and modify it so that you get the module name of the 2nd recursion.
After that, have a look at the resulting DXL code of the new column and modify it to your needs, in the style "if module name equals XXX then display yyyy"